# Error while computing Christoffel symbols with gravipy

Tags: python

I want to compute the Christoffel symbols of the 2nd kind for helix coordinates.
Therefore, I use the following program code in SageMath:

```
from sympy import init_printing
import inspect
init_printing()

ρ,ψ,ς,a  = symbols( 'ρ,ψ,ς,a ' )
x=Coordinates('x', [ ρ,ψ,ς  ] );

f=( ρ * cos(ψ+a*ς), ρ * sin(ψ+a*ς), ς );
Metric=jacobian(f, (ρ,ψ,ς) ).transpose() * jacobian(f, (ρ,ψ,ς) );

g=MetricTensor('g', x, Metric );
Ga = Christoffel('Ga', g);
```

There is no error message when I run these commands. But `Ga` seems to be empty, so         `Ga(All,All,All)` returns the error:

`AttributeError: 'sage.symbolic.expression.Expression' object has no attribute 'together'`

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any reply!!!

I found the following code which runs without problems and gives back my symbols:

```
# define some symbolic variables
t, r, theta, phi, M = symbols('t, r, \theta, \phi, M')
# create a coordinate four-vector object instantiating 
# the Coordinates class
x = Coordinates('\chi', [t, r, theta, phi])
# define a matrix of a metric tensor components
Metric = diag(-(1-2*M/r), 1/(1-2*M/r), r**2, r**2*sin(theta)**2)  
# create a metric tensor object instantiating the MetricTensor class
g = MetricTensor('g', x, Metric)
Ga = Christoffel('Ga', g)
Ga(All, All, All )
```

Comment: I found out what is wrong: I have to replace Metric=jacobian(f, (ρ,ψ,ς) ).transpose() * jacobian(f, (ρ,ψ,ς) ) by Metric=Matrix(jacobian(f, (ρ,ψ,ς) ).transpose() * jacobian(f, (ρ,ψ,ς) )), it seems that you have to convert a sagemath matrix to sympy matrix. Now it works.

Comment: Good:) If you think you solved the problem you can post it as an answer (and eventually  mark it as the correct one)